# Combine and append text from different richtextBoxes into one richTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Ok guys, so I need some help with a project I am making (no this isn't a school project, yes I'm fairly* new to coding)
Before I made this post I searched all over the internet and this site looking for guidance myself and found nothing that was useful
to help me do what I want this to do. I made a little layout of what i have vs. what I am trying to accomplish here.

A little text explanation: I want take my keyword textbox(these are all richtextboxes to clarify) which would be textbox1
in the chart, and i want to append text from eachbox to the end of each other until all combinations are added to the end of
the 1st item in text box one, then repeat for the second item

Visual explanation:This is my starting point

```
richtextbox 1          richtextbox2          richtextbox3          richtextbox4


item1textbox1string      item1textbox2string     item1textbox3string     item1textbox4string

item2textbox1string      item2textbox2string     item2textbox3string     item2textbox4string

item3textbox1string      item3textbox2string     item3textbox3string     item3textbox4string

item4textbox1string      item4textbox2string     item4textbox3string     item4textbox4string
```

this is the outcome desired...

```
item1textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item1textbox3string + item1textbox4string
item1textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item1textbox3string + item2textbox4string
item1textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item1textbox3string + item3textbox4string
item1textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item1textbox3string + item4textbox4string
```

after all items complete from listbox2-4 on the first string from textbox one I want to then restart on item 2 from textbox1 and repeat the process for remaining textbox1 items.

```
item1textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item2textbox3string + item1textbox4string
item1textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item2textbox3string + item2textbox4string
item1textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item2textbox3string + item3textbox4string
item1textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item2textbox3string + item4textbox4string

item1textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item3textbox3string + item1textbox4string
item1textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item3textbox3string + item2textbox4string
item1textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item3textbox3string + item3textbox4string
item1textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item3textbox3string + item4textbox4string

item1textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item4textbox3string + item1textbox4string
item1textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item4textbox3string + item2textbox4string
item1textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item4textbox3string + item3textbox4string
item1textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item4textbox3string + item4textbox4string

item1textbox1string + item2textbox2string + item1textbox3string + item1textbox4string
item1textbox1string + item2textbox2string + item1textbox3string + item2textbox4string
item1textbox1string + item2textbox2string + item1textbox3string + item3textbox4string
item1textbox1string + item2textbox2string + item1textbox3string + item4textbox4string
```

and so on until textbox 1 items are completed.

then repeat for item 2 and so on...

```
item2textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item1textbox3string + item1textbox4string
item2textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item1textbox3string + item2textbox4string
item2textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item1textbox3string + item3textbox4string
item2textbox1string + item1textbox2string + item1textbox3string + item4textbox4string
```

I've included a picture of a program that does what im trying to do essentially. I apologize in advance for the poor format, its hard to type in this thing.

What i'm trying to achieve:
[image: this is what im trying to acheive]

Current Layout:
[image: my current program layout]

Comment: thanks for editing the format to make it more readable, im new to stackoverflow, i will try my best to keep the formatting better.@Filburt. @TerribleDog

Comment: Save all the strings first from each rich textbox columns into **string collection** then use loops to append each combination of string every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this as a sample for the logic I told you in the comment. By saving the strings into a collection, you can easily manipulate them using iteration:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] c1 = { "Mik", "Don", "Sundar", "Neil" };
        string[] c2 = { "Kim", "Joy", "Fred", "Roi" };
        string[] c3 = { "Mae", "LA", "Ej", "Bob" };
        string[] c4 = { "Yin", "Yang", "Ching", "Chong" };

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        {
            string output = "";
            output += c1[i] + " "; 

            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                string output1 = output;
                output1 += c2[j] + " ";

                for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
                {
                    string output2 = output1;
                    output2 += c3[k] + " ";

                    for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++)
                    {
                        string output3 = output2;
                        output3 += c4[l] + " ";
                        Console.WriteLine(output3 + "\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

[Link to Output Strings](https://anotepad.com/notes/6j23kb5)

It produces all possible combinations of strings. You can also use **List** to store all strings for each category.

Comment: thanks so much for your help, I tried your suggested code and while i'm sure it was my error (please keep in mind i'm a novice coder) I could only get the last name of each box from your code to show up in my **result** textbox [see here](https://gyazo.com/6491ce4fde6329a64ca004da79ffe531) and when i tried my own richTextBoxes i got an error [see here](https://gyazo.com/cbca309022483e1bc9b5f6c17c64e991) im sorry for the trouble, I usually try to figure things out of my own but this one has really been kicking my butt. again, thanks for all your help, i upvoted your answer.

Comment: @DevSecLoki It will go out of bounds because the array "c4" does not contain 4 strings inside it. Insert all the strings into te respective array, change the value of 4 to "array size" and the do the loop.

Comment: @DevSecLoki you see, I declared the arrays with each respective strings, 4 exactly, that is why I used in the loops. For exact and flexible output, use array size or count , **array.Count()**.

Comment: ok so i am probably annoying you but trust me i'm trying lol. so ive been working and researching a couple days trying to get this to work like you did but i think i am calling from my text files wrong or something, using the method you provided i can only get the results to show the actual string path "@"C:\AIO\Clean_HoneyPot.txt"" or show "system.string[]" ....frustration is setting in. i called my text files like this....     string c1 = @"C:\AIO\Clean_HoneyPot.txt";      and also like this...      
            string[] c2 = { @"C:\AIO\Dork\Domain Extentions\common.txt" };

Comment: Use a loop to append all strings in your text file into a string array/collection. You need to use a TextReader for that

Comment: I GOT IT!!!!!! lol thanks so much for the help, i got the info like this,..  string[] c1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\AIO\Clean_HoneyPot.txt"); and implemented your method, gunna mark as answered. thanks again, truly.

Comment: No problem @DevSecLoki